# SQL Server: How to change collation of all columns of my select on the fly

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I need to query something from a table in my database but the collation of some columns are different from the one I need.

I found how to change the collation of one column on the fly like this:

```
SELECT 
  u.name  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AS 'User'(...)
```

But the problem is that are more than 150 columns that need a COLLATION change on the fly (don't ask me why because we can't change the collation of the entire table even though I think it would be the best option).

So the main question is:
`Is there a way to set the COLLATION to all columns of my query?`

Comment: Copy the list of columns into Excel, make a formula which generates the collation expression, paste back into your SQL window.

Comment: Do you have permissions to execute dynamic SQL on your server instance?

Comment: It would seem you have another problem you aren't explaining. For example, do you need to do this to join to temp tables (with a different collation)

Comment: Agree with Nick - most likely an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to change the collation of all text columns on the fly -- but manipulating the query to achieve the same result is doable. [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53723565/4137916) shows one way to do it, here's another using the metadata of the query. As a benefit, it's cursorless, and it avoids gratuitously introducing "new" columns if the collation is already what we want. It requires at least SQL Server 2012 to have `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`, and SQL Server 2017 to have `STRING_AGG` (on previous versions, the classic tricks for string concatenation can be used, like the `FOR XML PATH` trick).

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM MyTable';
DECLARE @tweakedQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @tweakedCollation SYSNAME = N'Latin1_General_CI_AS';

SELECT @tweakedQuery = CONCAT(
    'SELECT ', 
    STRING_AGG(
        CONCAT(
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), QUOTENAME([name])), 
            CASE 
                WHEN collation_name IS NOT NULL AND collation_name <> @tweakedCollation
                THEN ' COLLATE ' + @tweakedCollation + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME([name]) 
            END
        ), 
        ', ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    ),
    ' FROM (' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10),
    @query,
    CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ') _'
)
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@query, NULL, NULL);
PRINT @tweakedQuery;
```

Incorporating custom aliases would be simple, if they're generated systematically (based on the table or column name). Otherwise you'll have to patch things up manually.

For a one-off query (not something you necessarily need to do on the fly) it's still a much better idea to familiarize yourself with using regexes in your favorite editor. If your favorite editor has no regexes, get one that does.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there's a way of forcing a default collation for all columns of the output in this way.

However, if your server permits you to use dynamic SQL, you could build a dynamic query and execute it to get the result your looking for.

An example of this working is shown below. Please change `YOUR_TABLE_NAME` to your actual table name in order for it to work:

```
DECLARE @col    VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @sql    VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @table  VARCHAR(200)
SET @table = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';

-- Use a cursor to read all varchar columns from table
DECLARE curColumns CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY
  FOR
    SELECT  c.name
      FROM  sys.columns c
        INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
      WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table) AND
            t.name = 'varchar'

SET @sql = 'SELECT'

-- Go through column cursor
OPEN curColumns
FETCH NEXT FROM curColumns INTO @col
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    -- Add column to SQL with collation
    SET @sql = @sql + ' ' + @col + ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,'

    FETCH NEXT FROM curColumns INTO @col
END
CLOSE curColumns
DEALLOCATE curColumns

-- Add the from clause
SET @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 0, LEN(@sql) - 1) + ' FROM ' + @table

-- Uncomment this line to see the generated SQL
--PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

Note that there are several limitations to the above example:

1. You server must permit the running of dynamic SQL.
2. In this example, only `VARCHAR` columns are output (you can change this by changing the cursor query to include more types).
3. There is no way to specify column aliases using this method.